# Yearly Job Using T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, jobs, sql-server-agent

Can someone help me to create Yearly Job Using T-SQL? 
I wanted to execute the stored proc yearly.
I searched this ques in list of ques which are already asked but not able to get it.

Comment: You have to set it up to run monthly, every 12 months. There isn't a "yearly" option but this is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to setup a job (like a scheduled task).

Is this what you are after? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx